# BASH - weird characters coming out from a pipe

Tags: linux, bash, awk, grep, kill

I have this script which simply kills an app

```
KEY_NAME=/some/path
kill `ps -ef | grep $KEY_NAME | grep -v grep | awk '{ print $2 }'`
exit 0
```

If I write the kill command manually as a oneliner than it works. But I have to run it as a script which doesn't work. So I tried to debug it and here is the result

```
[user@server logs]$ bash -x ./script.sh
+ KEY_NAME=/some/path
++ ps -ef
++ grep /some/path
++ grep -v grep
++ awk '{ print $2 }'
+ kill $'20557\r'
: arguments must be process or job IDs
+ exit 0
```

Why do I keep getting those strange characters on the `kill` line? How can i get rid of them?

Comment: What happens if you add head -1 to that pipeline?

Comment: Have you tried `killall`? But if you're killing your own program, [you might want to reconsider](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement).

Comment: @l0b0 I haven't and I probably won't. I don't want to end up with killing more processes than I should have...

Comment: @Tomas: Then you should *really* read the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be the case is number of pid's returned are more than 1
Change your line to

```
ps -ef | grep $KEY_NAME | grep -v grep | awk '{ print $2 }'|xargs kill
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason you get gibberish chars is probably (I can't verify it because I don't have access to your environment) due to the subshell returning more than one line.

Try this:

```
KEY_NAME=/some/path
for pid in $(ps -ef | grep $KEY_NAME | grep -v grep | awk '{ print $2 }')
  do
    kill $pid
  done
exit 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You could replace all that with a call to [`pkill`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pkill). With the `-f` option, the full command line is used for matching (not just the process name) so you can still match against paths.

```
pkill -f $KEY_NAME
```

Apart from being simpler, it gives you easier control over what to kill, e.g. killing only processes owned by a specific user/group or only the oldest/newest.